# DynamoDB doesn't show items in order

Tags: nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I have over 800 data in `AWS DynamoDB`.

I configured `id` as `partition key` and its format is `4 digit number` as `String`

( e.g `0001`, `0050`, `0800`.)

But, I can't see what I expected.

[image]

How can I see them with alignment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DynamoDB does not sort the items it returns to you by their `partition key`. If you want items to be sorted be `field_x` you need to define `field_x` as a `sort key`.

However, for the time being you are only going to store small amounts of data (800 items is certainly considered "small", or even "tiny", from DynamoDB's point of view) you can just do the sorting on your side.

Comment: AFAIK, I can't edit the configure of the Table, is it correct? Do I have to re-create the table?

Comment: you can add a new GSI (Global Secondary Index) on your existing table. you can define the partion and sort keys on your GSI as you desire, thus saving you from re-creating the table

Comment: I'm confused, I thought `partition key` is the `unique`. but It is wrong. so, What could be `unique key` if you store the **lottery winning number**?